axios get url response - no data in calling function in setInterval
I'm trying to use setInterval which should perform a fetch every 60 secs. The axios response data has a valid value but if i try to assign it to a variable, it does not work.
Am I missing something?
async function fetch_data() {
axios
    .get("https://url.tld/data")
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data); // shows data
        return res.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        callback({ success: false, error: "could not fetch data" });
    });
}

setInterval(async () => {
let data = null;
  try {
    data = await fetch_data();
    console.log("Fetched data:", data); // is null
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
  }
}, 60000);


It looks like you just forgot to return the Promise in your fetch_data function?  return axios.get(...

Also... Where do you ever call fetch_data or observe its result?  How are these two pieces of code related, and which specific operation isn't doing what you expect?  (I suspect that you meant to make fetch_data and fetch_metadata the same function.  But they aren't.  We can make a variety of assumptions about what that means regarding the problem, but it's really up to you to provide a [mcve] and details about the problem.)

I fixed the code. fetch_data and fetch_metadata is the same.

The main issue is that the fetch_data function is not properly returning the fetched data.
const axios = require('axios'); // Ensure axios is imported

async function fetch_data() {
try {
    const res = await axios.get("https://url.tld/data");
    console.log(res.data);
    return res.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    return null;
  }
}

setInterval(async () => {
  try {    const data = await fetch_data();
    console.log("Fetched data:", data); 
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
  }}, 60000);


Thank you. That solves the problem. I know get the data. I see that i missed the "return" in my function.

If you encounter any issues like this, feel free to ping me.

You are expecting your data will resolved within 60 second which is not the case.
Javascript will assign values after executing all the async operations in this case.
try using Promise instead.

The code shown doesn't make any assumptions about data resolving after 60 seconds.  It just repeats the same operation every 60 seconds.  However, fetch_metadata isn't defined anywhere and fetch_data doesn't return anything.  (Well, technically it returns a Promise because it's async, but that Promise resolves immediately and produces no value.)
